# Not able to update url and update webview

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx-8

This is my project setup I'm trying to update the webview so each tab will be updated by one address bar. I cant seem to find where I'm going wrong. I'm new to javaFX. I know I have to add another change listener in there for the search button just not sure how...I cant find anything on how to do this. except one example that didnt really explain anything and the code was messy.

```
public class Client extends Application {   
    private Scene scene;
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    Browser browseR = new Browser();
    final TabPane tabs = new TabPane();
    final Tab home = new Tab("Home");
    final Tab newtab = new Tab("+");

    HBox hbox = new HBox();
    public static TextField addressBar = new TextField();
    final Group group = new Group(tabs,root,hbox); //joins the borderpane and browser element together

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {

        // create the scene
        stage.setTitle("Web Browser");
        scene = new Scene(group,screenSize.getWidth(),screenSize.getHeight(), Color.web("#666970")); //create scene with root pane and browser pane

        hbox.setSpacing(10);
        hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;");
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(5, 24, 5, 12));

        Button backButton = new Button("<");
        backButton.setOnAction(this::backButtonHandler);
        backButton.setPrefSize(25, 20);

        Button forwardButton = new Button(">");
        forwardButton.setOnAction(this::forwardButtonHandler);
        forwardButton.setPrefSize(25, 20);

        HBox.setHgrow(addressBar, Priority.ALWAYS);
        //addressBar.setMaxWidth(screenSize.getWidth()-200);

        Button searchButton = new Button("go");
        searchButton.setOnAction(this::searchButtonHandler);

        //add all menu elements to the top of the screen
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(backButton, forwardButton,addressBar,searchButton);

        setConstraints(tabs,hbox,stage);
        createHomeTab();   
        createNewTab();



        tabs.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Tab>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Tab> observable, Tab oldSelectedTab, Tab newSelectedTab) {
                if(newSelectedTab == newtab) {
                    final Tab tab = new Tab(browseR.getWebTitle());
                    tabs.getTabs().add(tab);
                    tabs.getSelectionModel().select(tab);
                    tab.setContent(new Browser());
                    loadFavicon(addressBar.getText(),tab);
                }
            }

            });

        root.setTop(hbox);
        root.setCenter(tabs);

        browseR.updateAddress();

        stage.setScene(scene);     
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void setConstraints(TabPane tabs, HBox hbox, Stage stage) {
        hbox.prefWidthProperty().bind(stage.widthProperty());
        tabs.prefHeightProperty().bind(stage.heightProperty());
    }

    private void backButtonHandler(ActionEvent event) {
        browseR.goBack();
    }
    public void createHomeTab() {
        tabs.getTabs().addAll(newtab,home);
        tabs.getSelectionModel().select(home);
        home.setContent(new Browser());
        loadFavicon(Browser.getHomePage(),home);
    }
    private void forwardButtonHandler(ActionEvent event) {
        browseR.goForward();
    }
    public void createNewTab() {
        newtab.setText(" + ");  
        newtab.setClosable(false);
    }
    private void searchButtonHandler(ActionEvent event) {
        Browser.navigate(addressBar.getText());
    }
    void loadFavicon(String location, Tab tab) {
      try {
        String faviconUrl = String.format("http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=%s", URLEncoder.encode(location, "UTF-8"));
        Image favicon = new Image(faviconUrl, true);
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(favicon);
        tab.setGraphic(iv);
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
          throw new RuntimeException(ex); // not expected
      }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //new Config();
        launch(args);
    }
}

public class Browser extends Region { 
    public static WebView browser = new WebView();
    public static WebEngine webEngine = getBrowser().getEngine();
    static String[] websites = {"http://www.google.com"};
    private static String homePage = websites[0];

    public Browser() {
        //apply the styles
        getStyleClass().add("browser");
        // load the web page
        webEngine.load(homePage);
        //add the web view to the scene
        getChildren().add(getBrowser());

    }

    public static void navigate(String website) {
        String google = "http://www.google.com/search?q=";
        String charset = "UTF-8";
        if(website.contains("http")) {
            webEngine.load(website);

            //debug
            System.out.println("found http");
        }
        else {
            try {
                webEngine.load(google+ URLEncoder.encode(website, charset));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //debug
        System.out.println(website);
    }
    /*
    private Node createSpacer() {
        Region spacer = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
        return spacer;
    }
     */     
    public String getWebTitle() {
        return webEngine.getTitle();
    }
    public void goBack() {
         Platform.runLater(() -> {
                webEngine.executeScript("history.back()");
            });
    }
    public String updateAddress() {
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
             if (Worker.State.SUCCEEDED.equals(newValue)) {
                 Client.addressBar.setText(webEngine.getLocation());
             }
         });
        return null;
    }
    public void goForward() {
     Platform.runLater(() -> {
                webEngine.executeScript("history.forward()");
            });
   }
    @Override protected void layoutChildren() {
        double w = getWidth();
        double h = getHeight();
        layoutInArea(getBrowser(),0,0,w,h,0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
    }

    @Override protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
        return 750;
    }

    @Override protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
        return 500;
    }
    //getters and setters
    public static String getHomePage() {
        return homePage;
    }
    public static void setHomePage(String homePage) {
        Browser.homePage = homePage;
    }

    public static WebView getBrowser() {
        return browser;
    }
```

Comment: You only seem to create one `Browser`. Unless I understand this the wrong way, don't you want a different browser in each tab?

Comment: Yes i do create a new browser when the public void changed is called

Comment: Oh, yes: didn't see it buried in there.

Comment: its controlling that tabs contents or web-engine once I've created it... i don't know if referencing the class is the right way to do it.

Comment: Why are you making the `WebView`, etc, static, if you want multiple web views to be visible in the application?

Comment: I was trying to reference the webview to the client class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you have a single text field, and multiple tabs, each with a browser. When an action occurs on the text field, you want to update the location of the browser in the currently selected tab.

The easiest way is to keep a reference to the currently displayed browser:

```
public class Client extends Application {   

    private Browser displayedBrowser ;

    // ...

}
```

When you create a new tab and browser, add a listener to the tab's `selectedProperty` which updates the `displayedBrowser` field:

```
tabs.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Tab>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Tab> observable, Tab oldSelectedTab, Tab newSelectedTab) {
        if(newSelectedTab == newtab) {
            final Tab tab = new Tab(browseR.getWebTitle());
            tabs.getTabs().add(tab);

            Browser newBrowser = new Browser();
            tab.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
                if (isNowSelected) {
                    displayedBrowser = newBrowser ;
                }
            });

            tabs.getSelectionModel().select(tab);

            tab.setContent(newBrowser);

            loadFavicon(addressBar.getText(),tab);
        }
    }

});
```

Now `displayedBrowser` will always point to the browser in the currently-selected tab.

Obviously, `navigate` cannot be a static method, since you want to navigate a specific browser: in fact *nothing* in the `Browser` class should be static: remove *all* occurrences of the `static` keyword from the `Browser` class. Once you make those changes you can just update the current browser:

```
private void searchButtonHandler(ActionEvent event) {
    displayedBrowser.navigate(addressBar.getText());
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you!!!! I've been banging my head against the wall for a few days now. Sorry I'm still learning java and i don't know the lingo yet, thank you for all of your help

Comment: So when we create a new tab when should we update the information on the address bar and tab names.. i've been playing with it and im not seeing the updates as im changing the url and move tabs