# Updating a textfield from another class

Tags: java, javafx-8

I'm trying to change the text of a textfield being handled by another class.

```
public String updateAddress() {
    webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
         if (Worker.State.SUCCEEDED.equals(newValue)) {
             Client.addressBar.setText(webEngine.getLocation());     
         }
     });
    return null;
}
```

but this only works if the textfield is static.

When I try to create a method that updates the textfield Java just crashes. I'm trying to create a multi tabbed browser so this method would update the address bar when the current tab I'm on is selected.

Comment: can you post the error you're getting? Also, what is `Client`? I'm confused by the capital letter: by convention `addressBar` would be a static field, so I'm not sure what you're working with here A little more context would be useful.

Comment: Client is the main class that handles the scene. the address bar is located in the client class. java just crashes when i run this and eclipse doesnt log any errors

Comment: What do you mean "Java just crashes"? Don't you get a [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/2775450)?

Comment: No nothing at all its the weirdest thing eclipse comes back and says the program was terminated in console..... and nothing was logged.

Answer (score 0):

Into the action you set a tab as visible/selected you can put this code to set the address bar.

Comment: I have a class called "browser" and a class called "client" client is where the address bar is held and the browser class holds the web engine. i dont know if i can pass the webengine across to the other class like that....

Comment: @Lodington you have a class where you create all the tabs and put them into a list? Is not from this class where you set the selected tab? You can pass the client class to this controller class during the controller class construction and from the every time a user selects a tab set the address bar name like client.setAddressBar("name")

Comment: i have the source here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007277/not-able-to-update-url-and-update-webview?noredirect=1#comment87060394_50007277